# Nested IAsyncEnumerable function requires EnumeratorCancellation attribute?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation-token, iasyncenumerable

I'd like to know if I need to use `EnumeratorCancellation` when passing a cancellation token to my local function. I am thinking of using this code pattern often in the future:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyOuterFunctionAsync(
this Client client, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken,
int? limit = null) 
{
    return MyLocalFunction().
        TakeWhile(
            (_, index) => 
                limit is null ||
                index < limit.Value);
 
    async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyLocalFunction()
    {
       var request = CreateRequest();

       do 
       {
            var page = await request.GetAsync(cancellationToken);
            foreach (var item in page) 
            {
                yield return item;
            }
            request = GetNextPageRequest();
       }
       while (request is not null)
    }
}
```

Resharper doesn't mention the need for `EnumeratorCancellation`, and when I try to add it to the outer function it says it will have no effect, but if I try adding it to the local function Resharper stays happy, as without. Should I use it anywhere?
I checked the IL viewer but I don't see any difference between the versions.

Will MyOuterFunctionAsync work properly? Do I need to change MyLocalFunction signature to

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyLocalFunction(
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer directly your question, the `MyOuterFunctionAsync` will recognize correctly a `CancellationToken` passed as argument, but not if the `CancellationToken` is passed with the `WithCancellation` operator. For example if:

```
var sequence = client.MyOuterFunctionAsync(CancellationToken.None)
    .WithCancellation(token);
```

...the `token` will be ignored. For correct behavior you do have to add the `EnumeratorCancellation` attribute in the `MyLocalFunction`.

You could consider adopting the pattern used in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) library. For example the [`Where`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9fb0ed0d0160902ca550c44f6d2f89f54b0b53c7/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Where.cs#L45-L71) LINQ operator:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
    if (predicate == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(predicate));

    return Core(source, predicate);

    static async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Core(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await foreach (var element in source.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see the outer `Where` is not `async`, and the inner `Core` is `async`. The public signature of the `Where` doesn't include a `CancellationToken` parameter. The caller can always use the [`WithCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.withcancellation) operator to attach a `CancellationToken` to an asynchronous sequence, so including a parameter is redundant. For example:

```
var query = sequence.Where(x => x.IsAvailable).WithCancellation(token);
```

On the other hand the local `Core` implementation of the operator does include a `CancellationToken` parameter, which is also decorated with the [`EnumeratorCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.enumeratorcancellationattribute) attribute. When the caller uses the `Where` and attaches a token with the `WithCancellation`, this token is automatically passed to the `Core` implementation because of the `EnumeratorCancellation` attribute.

**So the general rule is:** A method that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` should include an `CancellationToken` parameter only if it's implemented with [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async), in which case the parameter should also be decorated with the `EnumeratorCancellation` attribute.

Ideally public APIs that return `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` should not be implemented with `async`. That's because giving to the caller two different options to pass a token, either directly or through the `WithCancellation`, creates confusion without adding any value to the API. As an example of what **not** to do, see the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5ab45c79c06e05e146cf2f45993d51c87a275118/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs#L18-L27) of the [`ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync) API.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! While this is highly enlightening, and I'll definitely use the approach you provided in my code, it does not answer my question. The code I posted is used in a very specific environment and complies with the specific company's guidelines. Will the snippet I posted work, or do I need to add a CancellationToken to the local function with EnumeratorCancellation attribute?

Comment: I just found [this Roslyn issue response by jcouv](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40893#:~:text=ignored/useless%20there.-,What%20you%20want%20to%20do,-here%20is%20add). It looks like I should add a CancellationToken parameter with [EnumeratorCancellation] attribute to the local function, but the reason is left unexpained

Comment: @Zapdor ah, yes, sorry, I was carried away. I edited my answer and added a direct answer to your question at the bottom.